# UIPrintInteractionController and Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I have been using UIPrintInteractionController, the app was working fine in iOS 8, but since iOS 9 I keep getting errors logged when trying to print, and it is not consistent. I found a basic AirPrint app example on-line for UIPrintInteractionController and it has the same problems, which are:

1- Running the app on all simulators (iOS 9 only) and my 6S device I get the following logged:

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController

2- When running app on on 5s or 6sPlus simulators I get the above erros plus:

2016-01-04 14:15:20.087 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:

2016-01-04 14:15:20.087 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

2016-01-04 14:15:20.088 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: .

2016-01-04 14:15:20.088 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

2016-01-04 14:15:20.093 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:

2016-01-04 14:15:20.093 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
 2016-01-04 14:15:20.094 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 250}> collection view layout: .

2016-01-04 14:15:20.094 AirPrint-Test[76720:38159873] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

I have tried:

1. delaying the presentAnimated method using a timer as well as dispatch_async
2. turning off animation
3. only calling presentAnimated if ( [self isViewLoaded] )
4. using UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter instead of the NSData(no PDF file)

It seems to be because of the new print preview in iOS 9

the app code:

```
viewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController      <UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

- (IBAction)printButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)printButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AirPrintTest" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];


UIPrintInteractionController *printDocController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(printDocController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: myData] ) {

    printDocController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printDocController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printDocController.showsPageRange = YES;
    printDocController.printingItem = myData;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printDocController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        //self.content = nil;
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
        }
    };

   [printDocController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];



   }
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: I have been dealing with the exact same issue recently.   I have found this issue occurs consistently when I run ***in a simulator*** or ***if I debug using Xcode on an actual device*** (iPhone 7 plus).  In my case my project deployment target is iOS 9.0 and I am running on iOS 10.  I'm not sure if this is a factor.  This is not a solution, but In a nutshell I have found that if I build onto the device and then run the app normally, not debugging in Xcode, it will work.  Very Strange.